# How to use associatedType protocol in vars or arrays throught `some` in Swift 5.1?

Tags: swift, swift5

**I tried to make array or var comform to `ProtocolA` but I ran into some errors.**
What is going on here?

I created two protocols with/without `associatedtype` and made two `struct` conform to `ProtocolA` and `ProtocolB`

```swift
protocol ProtocolA {
    associatedtype ProtocolAType

    var prop1: ProtocolAType { get set }

    func description()
    func methodA(param1: ProtocolAType) -> ProtocolAType
}

protocol ProtocolB {
    func description()
}

extension ProtocolA {
    func description() {
        print(self)
    }

    func methodA(param1: ProtocolAType) -> ProtocolAType {
        param1
    }
}

struct StructA: ProtocolA, ProtocolB {
    var prop1: Int
}

struct StructB: ProtocolA, ProtocolB {
    var prop1: String
}
```

I created `CustomCollection` to pass some type.

```swift
struct CustomCollection<T> {
    typealias Items = [T]

    private var items: Items

    init(items: Items) {
        self.items = items
    }
}

extension CustomCollection: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    init(arrayLiteral elements: T...) {
        self.items = elements
    }
}

extension CustomCollection: Collection {
    typealias Index = Items.Index
    typealias Element = Items.Element

    var startIndex: Index { items.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Index { items.endIndex }

    subscript(index: Index) -> Iterator.Element {
        get { items[index] }
        set { items[index] = newValue }
    }

    func index(after i: Index) -> Index {
        items.index(after: i)
    }
}
```

`CustomCollection` works ok with non-associated type protocols.

```swift
var items: CustomCollection<ProtocolB> = [StructA(prop1: 1), StructB(prop1: "1")]
for item in items {
    item.description()
}
```

I tried to call `methodA` but I got errors below.

```swift
var item1: some ProtocolA = StructA(prop1: 1)
var item2: some ProtocolA = StructB(prop1: "1")

item1.description()

//Cannot invoke 'methodA' with an argument list of type '(param1: Int)'
var result1 = item1.methodA(param1: 1)
//Cannot invoke 'methodA' with an argument list of type '(param1: String)'
var result2 = item2.methodA(param1: "1")
```

I don't know to make `[ProtocolA]`

```swift
//Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to specified type 'some ProtocolA'
//Property declares an opaque return type, but cannot infer the underlying type from its initializer expression
var items1: some ProtocolA = [StructA(prop1: 1), StructB(prop1: "1")]
//Property declares an opaque return type, but cannot infer the underlying type from its initializer expression
//Return type of var 'items2' requires that '[StructA]' conform to 'ProtocolA'
var items2: some ProtocolA = [StructA(prop1: 1), StructA(prop1: 1)]
```

**I'd like to call `methodA`.**

```
for item in items1 {
    item.methodA(2)
}
for item in items2 {
    item.methodA("2")
}
```

**I mist how to specify the `associatedtype`**

```swift
//Protocol 'ProtocolA' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
var items4: CustomCollection<ProtocolA> = [StructA(prop1: 1), StructB(prop1: "1")]
//An 'opaque' type must specify only 'Any', 'AnyObject', protocols, and/or a base class
var items5: some CustomCollection<ProtocolA> = [StructA(prop1: 1), StructB(prop1: "1")]
```

I wouldn't like to use casting at the call site, like below

```swift
var items: some Collection = [StructA(prop1: 1), StructB(prop1: "1")]
for item in items {
    if let item = item as? StructA {
        item.methodA(param1: 4)
    }
    if let item = item as? StructB {
        item.methodA(param1: "3")
    }
}
```

I'd like to use something like below

```swift
var items: some CustomCollection<ProtocolA> = [StructA(prop1: 1), StructA(prop1: 2)]
for item in items {
    item.methodA(param1: 4)
}
```

**I suppose I will have to make different protocols for all supported types without associated types. This one way or has another's?**

Comment: `ProtocolA` is associated type protocol. I do not know how to specify the type of `ProtocolA` to make [ProtocolA] to call `methodA`. I know how to make non-associated type protocol array to call `methodA`.

Comment: I updated my questions to be more clear. `ProtocolB` isn't problem I added it to compare with `ProtocolA`. I have issues with `ProtocolA` since it has `associatedtype`

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think that is possible. ProtocolA can only be used as a generic constraint. You will get the same errors if you try to create an array of FloatingPoint types.

Comment: Regarding your methodA you can make it generic `func methodA<T: ProtocolA>(param1: T) -> T`

Comment: Can you write how to make it?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dhn27p6e9ck06z/Playground%20Protocols.playground.zip?dl=1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208351/discussion-between-victor-kushnerov-and-leo-dabus).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you just can't.

The explanation quite is simple, in fact, for Swift your array needs to contain elements of the same "type". When your protocol has no associated type, that's easy, your array contains `ProtocolB` instances...

But when an associated type (or Self) is involved `ProtocolA` is not enough. Because `ProtocolA` does not mean anything alone, it needs its associated type. More precisely you can't have in the same array `ProtocolA{Int}` and `ProtocolA{String}`.

So when you declare a variable or an array of `ProtocolA` the compiler can't know what associated type is... associated.

It is the same thing as generics in a way :

```
var x : Array = [3,4]
x = ["thing"] // You can't
```

The first line infers the type to `Array<Int>` so you can't assign an array of string...

But when you write :

```
var items: CustomCollection<ProtocolA> = [StructA(prop1: 1)]
```

It can't be inferred because the "real" type it would need, would be `CustomCollection<ProtocolA{Int}>` but there's not such thing in swift...

Worse, when you write:

```
var items: CustomCollection<ProtocolA> = [StructA(prop1: 1), StructB(prop1: "1")]
```

You have elements of `ProtocolA{Int}` and `ProtocolA{String}`.

**Note**: When I write `ProtocolA{Int}` it's just a way of clarifying that the protocol itself needs its associated type, not some kind of syntax.

**EDIT**: For your last question, can't you do something like that?

```
protocol ProtocolAA {
    func description()
}

extension ProtocolAA {
    func description() {
        print(self)
    }

    func methodA<T>(param1: T) -> T {
        param1
    }
}

struct StructA: ProtocolAA, ProtocolB {
    var prop1: Int
}

struct StructB: ProtocolAA, ProtocolB {
    var prop1: String
}

var items: CustomCollection<ProtocolAA> = [StructA(prop1: 1), StructA(prop1: 2), StructB(prop1: "X")]
for item in items {
    item.methodA(param1: 4)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see. Do you know another way how to implement it? 
I guess I will have to make protocols for all supported types without associated types.
I added "I wouldn't like to use casting at the call site, like below" section to my question.

Comment: Added "I'd like to use something like below"

Comment: I edited my answer to try and find some kind of solution using method genericity.